# How to deserialize complex JSON with dynamic keys in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

I have this complex JSON that looks like:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "statement_id": 0,
            "series": [
                {
                    "name": "test-name",
                    "tags": {
                        "tag1": "0"
                        "tag2": "1"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        "time",
                        "mean"
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        [
                            "2018-12-03T10:18:37.3Z",
                            0
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The POCO for the above is like:

```
public class Tags
{
    public string tag1 { get; set; }
    public string tag2 { get; set; }
}

public class Series
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Tags tags { get; set; }
    public List<string> columns { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> values { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int statement_id { get; set; }
    public List<Series> series { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, properties in `Tags` class are dynamic. There can be just one tag, 2 or more which is only determined at runtime.

I'm trying to use `Newtonsoft.Json` to parse this to a nested dictionary like `Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<string, object[]>>>` where the keys of the dictionaries are values of tags and the `object[]` contains the list of values (just the value, not the timestamp).

Comment: Can you getting rid of the `Tags` class and instead add this as a property for the Tags?

`public IDictionary<string, JToken> Tags { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2):

You should possibly use Dictionary instead of a Tag Class.

```
[JsonExtensionData]
public Dictionary<string,object> Tags{get;set;}
```

For example,

```
public class JsonSample
{
[JsonExtensionData]
public Dictionary<string,object> RandomKeyValuePair {get;set;}
}

// Sample Code
var jsonString = @"
{
'Key1' : 'some value 1',
'Key2' : 'some value 1',
'Key3' : 'some value 1',
'Key4' : 'some value 1',
}";



var jsonSampleObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonSample>(jsonString);
```

**Update**

Modified Series Class

```
public class Series
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string,JToken> tags { get; set; }
    public List<string> columns { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> values { get; set; }
}
```

Client Call

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(str);
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",result.results.First().series.First().tags.Select(x=>$"{x.Key}={x.Value},")));
```

Output

```
tags={
  "tag1": "0",
  "tag2": "1"
},
```

Please note there is an error in your Json. "," is missing after "tag1": "0"

Comment: How is this different from a simple `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(json)`? can't see how this helps me.

Comment: Consider a more complex data type than shown in example, perhaps something like yours. In that scenario too this would work.

Comment: Can you show me how you would do this with my json schema rather than this simplistic example you've shown?

Comment: @swdon I have updated the answer with sample code with your data structure

Answer (score 0):

Only change your `tags` property datatype in `Series` class from

```
public Tags tags { get; set; }
```

To

```
public Dictionary<string, JToken> tags { get; set; }
```

And then you will be able to parse dynamic key tags from your json.

So your `Series` class will be.

```
public class Series
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> tags { get; set; }
    public List<string> columns { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> values { get; set; }
}
```